# Apache Flume Kafka Producer - Generate partition_id/key dynamically

Tags: apache, configuration, flume-ng

I have a task to use Apache Flume to send messages to a Kafka topic.  The caveat is that I have to specify a partition based on an IP address that will be in the message.

Is there a way to configure Apache Flume to do this dynamically, or do I have to implement a custom Producer plugin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the only real custom way of configuring the producer is to roll your own.

I implemented the [AbstractSink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html) interface and put in my own hash algorithm to generate a partition to send the message to.